# Any Mac app (osx) I build crashes immediately after opening on another mac

Tags: macos, crash, osx-mavericks

So basically if I build any app (even the most simple hello world app) in xcode on my dev machine, then copy the "myapp.app" file to another mac, when I open it it appears in the dock for a fraction of a second then.. nothing (they all work on the dev machine).
I'm using Xcode 5.0.2 and both machines are running Mavericks (10.9.1) on 64bit.
Any help? I'm relatively new to building apps for the mac (have done some for ios), so not sure what could be wrong!

Comment: Do you have the symbolicated crash reports?

Comment: Is anything written to the console? The non-dev machine is probably missing a necessary framework, or something.

Comment: If I open any of the apps via the terminal I get "LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810". Hmmmmmm.

Comment: Console:
1/02/2014 3:15:03.020 pm mds[39]: (Warning) DiskStore: Server returned -1 setting attributes
1/02/2014 3:15:05.922 pm com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[150]: (com.nineswiss.test.37168[2202]) Job failed to exec(3) for weird reason: 13
1/02/2014 3:15:05.924 pm Finder[167]: 8837325: Attempting to SIGCONT to pid #2202 failed, with errno=#3, or the process failed to actually start
1/02/2014 3:15:05.926 pm Dock[164]: no information back from LS about running process LSASN:{hi=0x0;lo=0xb10b1}

Comment: and then:
1/02/2014 3:15:05.935 pm Finder[167]: 8837325: Attempting to SIGCONT to pid #2202 failed, with errno=#3, or the process failed to actually start

The above goes on for some time.

Comment: Is the machine in question set to require apps to be signed?

Comment: "Allow apps downloaded from:" is set to "anywhere".

Comment: It does seem like a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed!
I found the issue. For some reason if I copied the app to the non dev machine over my network it wouldn't run, if I airdop/usb etc the file it works fine. Weird.